# Based on condition txt file divided into two files in java

Tags: java

My target is i have one txt file it contains some line of text. in this i have two words i.e A and 1. if line has "A" letter then next lines goto one file until next line contain "1" and if line contain "1" then next lines goto other file until "A" find.

Input file like follows

```
A
rahu
pahdu
jhaani
1
hjsdh
dhj
A
jiko
raju
A
tenk
kouou
```

I am expecting output

A.txt contain

```
rahu
pahdu
jhaani
```

Same
1.txt

My code

```
{
    fis = new FileInputStream("E:\\Input.txt");
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    System.out.println("Reading File line by line using BufferedReader");

    String line = reader.readLine();
    while(line != null){
        if(line.contains("LETTER00~VSAQCCCC~H~")) {
            line = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        else {
            line= reader.readLine();
        }
    }           

}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: only one line i am printing after condition but i want print till "1" found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just repoint your `FileOutputStream` whenever you find a 1 or A.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("in.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    FileOutputStream fosA = new FileOutputStream("out_A.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream("out_1.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    System.out.println("Reading File line by line using BufferedReader");

    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        if(line.equals("A"))
        {
            fos = fosA;
            line = reader.readLine();
            continue;
        }

        if(line.equals("1"))
        {
            fos = fos1;
            line = reader.readLine();
            continue;
        }

        fos.write(line.getBytes());
        fos.write('\n');
        fos.flush();
        line = reader.readLine();
    }

    fos.close();
    fosA.close();
    fos1.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("Input.txt"));
    boolean isFound = false;
    List<String> main_list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> sub_list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if(line.contains("A")) {
            isFound = true;
        } else if(line.contains("1")) {
            isFound = false;
            for (String aSub_list : sub_list) {
                main_list.add(aSub_list);
            }
            sub_list.clear();
        }

        if(isFound && !line.contains("A")) {
            sub_list.add(line);
        }
    }

    for (String aMain_list : main_list) {
        System.out.println(aMain_list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now also it prints after A only one line but i want till 1 found

Comment: @B.AsiriNaidu I Updated the answer

Comment: thanks but now it skips single lines.  After "A" there is single line it skip that line for multiple lines it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
            System.out.println("Reading File line by line using 
            BufferedReader");
            String inputFIle = "";
            String line;
            boolean flag = false;
            // String line = reader.readLine();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                    inputFIle = "A.txt";
                } else if(line.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                    inputFIle = "1.txt";
                }
                else{
                    write(line, inputFIle);
                }
            }
```